# Styling checkboxes in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, forms

I've set up a form in Word using the following:
[image]

...so that users can tick / untick checkboxes, but the boxes appear greyed out.

Is there a way I can restyle them to look more like checkboxes do in a web browser?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the checkbox is always displayed with shading? If that is the case, you can go to Developer tab, click Shading to clear the shading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a Mac and there isn't much you can do to change the styling of the checkbox. You can remove the shading with the shading control that shows on the screen clip you provided. You can also change the box line color by using the Font color control on the Home tab.

Finally, with the box selected check the Options there are available by clicking that button. There you can change the size of the box.

Comment: thanks, I think I'm already using content controls however? I've just updated my answer

Comment: Since you are using a Mac, I have edited by answer.